# Rails + Postgis with spatial_adapter or postgis_adapter gem?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, rubygems, gis, postgis

I need to use Ruby-on-Rails together with a Postgis database.
Anyone experience with both [spatial_adapter](http://github.com/fragility/spatial_adapter) and [postgis_adapter](http://github.com/nofxx/postgis_adapter) gem?
What are the differences? Which do you recommend? Are there any other gems you recommend?

Comment: What are supposed to answer?  Yes?  Are you doing a survey?  This isn't a real question, if you're having a problem or you have a question please either edit your existing question so that it's something we can help you with or close this one and start a new one.

Comment: sorry if my question was unclear. just edited it, is it clear enough now?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

postgis_adapter was forked from spatial_adapter, so they are very similar. The key differences are:

- postgis_adapter provides additional instance methods over spatial_adapter
- postgis_adapter only supports one geom column per model
- postgis_adapter doesn't work with Rails 3

Comment: postgis_adapter has Rails 3 at least mentioned in the Readme now. But I didn't manage to get it to work, yet.